# Is there a way to use variables to define the database you are editing in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am using multiple database tables and need to use each one depending on what it is used for.

This is my current code

```
public function showLesson($type, $rank, $skill, $id) {
    $lessons = DB::select('select * from tbl where id = ?', [$id]);
    return view('admin.pages.edit-lesson', ['lessons' => $lessons]);
}
```

Is there a way to make it use a certain database using variables?

e.g: `DB::select('select * from "$type-$rank-$skill" where id = ?', [$id]);`

Comment: Usually that's a sign of poor schema design. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is a personal project. I am just trying to use multiple databases without trying to use if statements as they are very inefficient.

Comment: Multiple databases or tables? There's nothing intrinsically "inefficient" about `if`, but it may not be the appropriate call. Are you sure you can't do this through Eloquent?

Comment: Usually you can fold this into one query that looks like `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=? AND lesson_type=?` if required. Keeping them all in one table provides a lot of advantages. If you can't, use different models.

Comment: I have tried doing it through Eloquent  but it ddidn't work out too well so I just resorted to this. I am trying to use other tables depending on the URL. e.g https://website.com/admins/edit-lesson/{type}/{rank}/{skill}/{id} would be $type-$rank-$skill

Comment: @tadman I am not trying to use different columns. I am trying to use different tablenames.

Comment: That just sounds like different attributes in the same table you can filter on if necessary. Nothing in there suggests you'd *need* multiple tables. If you have three properties with N values each, that's a *lot* of tables if you need to store all that data, so that's instantly a huge mess from a relational perspective. Make one table with `type`, `rank` and `skill` columns.

Comment: I have different IDs for lessons. Is there a way to use variables like in normal PHP."<h2>" . $txt1 . "</h2>";

Comment: SQL does not allow nor encourage arbitrary interpolation of table names. Say it with me: **THIS IS A HIGHLY PROBLEMATIC SCHEMA DESIGN YOU DO NOT WANT TO COMMIT TO**. I've seen code-bases that have gone this way. The amount of work to un-do such a design decision is often incredible and it's something that can be *very* easily avoided.

Comment: Yea that is what I meant. How can I interpolate it into the query? I am guessing it would be `$lessons = DB::select('select * from '. $query .'where id = ?',[$id]);`

Comment: This is a huge problem, and a design you absolutely do not want to commit to. Why can't you express this as one table with properties as has been done for *decades* in relational database design? What exceptional circumstances are you battling here? If you can describe, it's possible to accommodate. See: [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) which is a well-defined area of study.

Comment: This is just to test out Laravel. The project is not for production so I don't want to spend hours redoing the tables if I can interpolate the database query.

Comment: Then just jam the table name in there. Keep in mind this is extremely dangerous unless you restrict which values are allowed. It's also worth noting that if you're testing out Laravel and not using Eloquent you're sort of missing the point. Eloquent works exceptionally well with a properly normalized schema. Normalizing your tables may take a little time now, but it'll be way easier to do at this junction than later on. It's probably just a dozen or so queries to merge them.

Comment: Thanks seems to work fine now. I will consider using what you mentioned above for production future projects.